# Is raspberry pi 4 with 4Gig ram with pivpn a good solution for office vpn

Tags: pi-4, vpn

Is raspberry pi 4 with 4Gig ram with pivpn a good solution for office vpn

We have 15-20 staff that would use the vpn. Network usage mostly will be for RDP.

Comment: Very unlikely.  All you have to do here is consider the available bandwidth and do some basic math.

Comment: Bandwidth isn't a problem. What I am trying to figure out is whether the Pi would be a bottleneck.

Comment: From previous testing with VPN's, its not RAM that will be the problem, more likely CPU. Unfortunately its hard to give a definite answer. Software like Pihole will run for multiple users on a new RPi with very little CPU usage. Try borrow one? or just buy one, without a case is quite cheap.

Comment: The Pi would be a bottleneck because of its limited bandwidth.  If you believe that is enough to serve 15-20 nodes actively with RDP, keeping in mind the amount that must pass through the Pi is effectively doubled, then the question is whether openVPN can keep up with that amount of traffic limited by the processing power of a Pi 4.  Pretty sure it can in the sense that I think if all the Pi is doing is running openVPN using TUN it will be able to keep up with whatever its external interfaces can deliver.  Maybe.  Probably. Don't quote me on that ;)

Comment: You should probably indicate what interface(s) are being used since that determines the max bandwidth, or else indicate exactly what the peak traffic volume will be in mbps, since this determines in linear relation how hard openVPN has to work.